# Foreign key constraint error in postgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, foreign-keys

I am making a database, but I get an error that apparently violates a foreign key constraint.
I am at a complete loss, I have tried to remake the DB.

It works if I change the productId to INT instead of SERIAL but i need the auto incrementing, and

```
[GENERATED { ALWAYS | BY DEFAULT } AS IDENTITY]
```

doesn't work either, because the inherited table can't see that it auto-generates and therefore wants me to enter a productId anyways.

The error code I get:

```
[23503] ERROR: insert or update on table "orderspec" violates foreign key constraint "orderspec_productid_fkey"
Detail: Key (productid)=(1) is not present in table "product".
```

It happens when i run this code:

```
INSERT INTO orderspec(orderno, productid, amount)
VALUES (1, 1, 50),
       (1, 2, 20);
```

I have made sure that there is matching data in the table, which is why i am so confused.

My tables are made like this:

```
--- ORDER TABLE ---
CREATE TABLE order_
(
    CVR        INT,
    orderNo    SERIAL,
    orderDate  DATE,
    totalPrice DECIMAL(9, 2),
    PRIMARY KEY (orderNo),
    FOREIGN KEY (CVR) REFERENCES customer (CVR)
);

-- ORDERSPEC TABLE --
CREATE TABLE orderspec
(
    orderNo   INT,
    productId INT,
    amount    INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (orderNo, productId),
    FOREIGN KEY (orderNo) REFERENCES order_ (orderNo),
    FOREIGN KEY (productId) REFERENCES product (productId)
);

-- PRODUCT TABLE --
-- "name" is a domain with a VARCHAR(128), no checks.
CREATE TABLE product
(
    productId     SERIAL,
    productName   name,
    measurement   VARCHAR,
    minPurchase   INT,
    producedBy    name,
    salesPrice    DECIMAL,
    bbDate        DATE,
    amountInStock DECIMAL,
    tags          VARCHAR,
    PRIMARY KEY (productId)
);


CREATE TABLE nonAlcoholicBeverage
(
    type VARCHAR,
    PRIMARY KEY (productId)
) INHERITS (product);
```

And my data inserts look like this:     (It's just dummy data)

```
INSERT INTO customer
VALUES (1, 'TEST_CUSTOMER');

INSERT INTO nonAlcoholicBeverage (productName, measurement, minPurchase, producedBy, salesprice, bbDate,
                                  amountInStock, tags, type)
VALUES ('Coffee', 'palle', 69, 'Moen-Kilback', 25, '2020-09-14 07:31:01', 704, 'knowledge user', 'kaffe'),
       ('Orangejuice', 'palle', 78, 'Cormier Group', 19, '2020-09-18 18:38:21', 242, 'clear-thinking', 'most');
```

Comment: The obvious question is whether there is a product with a `productId`(by the way mixed case is generally not a good idea) of 1 in `product`?

Comment: @Adrian Klaver There is. The mixed case is DataGrip that auto-lowers the case in some places, but it is not the issue in this case.